# TranslateX xaml in wpf c#

Tags: c#, wpf

i have problem to get value TranslateX of grid
i can set the value in grid by composite transform

```
 CompositeTransform dd = new CompositeTransform();
     CompositeTransform dd = new CompositeTransform();

        dd.TranslateX = Convert.ToInt32(tabl.x);
        dd.TranslateY = Convert.ToInt32(tabl.y);
        dd.Rotation = Convert.ToInt32(tabl.r);

        grid.RenderTransform = dd;
```

but i can't take the value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always access the existing `CompositeTransform` by the Grid's `RenderTransform` property. Therefore you should set the CompositeTransform once, preferably in XAML:

```
<Grid x:Name="grid">
    <Grid.RenderTransform>
        <CompositeTransform/>
    </Grid.RenderTransform>
</Grid>
```

Now you may write code like this:

```
var transform = (CompositeTransform)grid.RenderTransform;

// set values
transform.TranslateX = tabl.x;
transform.TranslateY = tabl.y;
transform.Rotation = tabl.r;

// get values
var x = transform.TranslateX;
var y = transform.TranslateY;
var r transform.Rotation;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the TranslateX Value of grid like this:

```
double translateX = (grid.RenderTransform as CompositeTransform).TranslateX;
```